# ros2 equivalent of catkin_find?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just trying to determine if a package is present in a given workspace, and where. I was kind of surprised to not find a `ros2 pkg find` subcommand. Is there something similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310739/ros2-equivalent-of-catkin_find?/) by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2018-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean before you build the workspace or after it is installed and you've sourced the setup file?

In the former case you have to ask `colcon` with something like this:

```
% colcon list | grep rviz
rviz2   /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz2  (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_assimp_vendor  /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_assimp_vendor (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_common /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_common    (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_default_plugins    /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_default_plugins   (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_ogre_vendor    /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_ogre_vendor   (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_rendering  /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_rendering_tests    /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering_tests   (ros.ament_cmake)
rviz_visual_testing_framework   /Users/william/ros2_ws/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_visual_testing_framework  (ros.ament_cmake)
```

For the latter there is `ros2 pkg ...` commands, e.g.:

```
% ros2 pkg list | grep rmw
rmw
rmw_connext_cpp
rmw_connext_shared_cpp
rmw_fastrtps_cpp
rmw_fastrtps_dynamic_cpp
rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp
rmw_implementation
rmw_implementation_cmake
rmw_opensplice_cpp
```

Or this:

```
% ros2 pkg prefix rclcpp
/Users/william/ros2_ws/install/rclcpp
```

If you're looking for something to do the grep for you, then we'd have to add a verb for that, but I think it would probably be accepted if a pr was made to that effect (after some iteration probably).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2